# Meu código php para envio de email não está sendo carregado

Tags: php, html, formulário, email, phpmailer

Eu tenho o seguinte código para enviar email do meu form

```html
<?php
// alterar a variavel abaixo colocando o seu email
$destino = "contato@lynx.eti.br";
// emails para quem será enviado o formulário
$assunto = "Contato pelo Site";

// // variaveis
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// // monta o e-mail na variavel $body
$body = "===================================" . "\n";
$body .= "Contato - TESTE" . "\n";
$body .= "===================================" . "\n\n";
$body .= "Nome: " . $name . "\n";
$body .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";
$body .= "Telefone: " . $phone . "\n";
$body .= "Assunto: " . $subject . "\n";
$body .= "Mensagem: " . $message . "\n\n";
$body .= "===================================" . "\n";

// // É necessário indicar que o formato do e-mail é html
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: $name <$email>';

////envio
mail("$destino, $assunto, $body, $headers");

////confimaçao
echo '<a href="Index.php">Voltar para formulário de cadastro</a>';
?>
```

e o meu codigo do formulario para chamar está função do php está assim

```html
   <form action="envio.php" method="post" name="form" class="col-md-9 go-right">
   <div class="form-group">
   <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required>
   <label for="name">Nome</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="form-control" required>
   <label for="email">Email</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" required>
   <label for="phone">Celular</label>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group">
   <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" required>
   <label for="subject">Assunto</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" required></textarea>
   <label for="message">Deixe sua mensagem</label>
  </div> 
   <button type="submit" value="submit">
     <input name="submit" value="Enviar"><br>
   </button>
  </form>
```

Aparentemente está tudo ok, mas quando clico em 'Enviar' ele carrega envio.php como se fosse uma pagina, ao invés de executar o código que está no arquivo. Claro que dá pagina não encontrada para envio.php, e o email não chega, pq acredito que o código não esteja sendo executado.

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigada.

Comment: Olá Caroline, um arquivo php deve ser estritamente terminado com a extensão ".php", verifique se na extensão do arquivo não foi criado algo após isso. Sugiro olhar pelo terminal.

Comment: Olá André, dei uma olhadinha aqui pelo terminal e está certinho mesmo, está envio.php

Comment: Você tem que ver se a função mail está ativa. Abra o `php.ini`, procure pela linha `[mail function]` e ajuste os valores de SMTP e smtp_port.

Comment: Eu acredito que esteja ativo sim, pois configurei atraves de um plugin no WP, e quando envio email teste por esse plugin, chega normalmente. Mas vou dar uma olhada aqui no arquivo php.ini só pra ter ctz.

Comment: Pelo que seu comentário indica, você não está com problema, especificamente, para enviar email, mas sim para interpretar um código PHP. Quando o Apache/IIS/Nginx/etc entregam explicitamente seu código fonte, significa que o PHP não está instalado corretamente. Obviamente isso deve ocorrer se você acessar qualquer outra página `PHP` neste mesmo ambiente. Ideal é identificar, primeiro, o que está ocorrendo com o seu ambiente para então começar a depurar seu script para envio de emails.

Comment: Outra coisa! Você está colocando os argumentos da chamada de `mail` entre aspas: `mail("$destino, $assunto, $body, $headers");`. Está errado! Você transformou o que deveriam ser vários argumentos em um único argumento (string).

Comment: Olá, na verdade não. Todas as paginas são php e todas funcionam normalmente, o php está rodando ok, mas vou fazer as dicas que me passaram, caso não de certo tento esta alternativa.

Comment: Então, outro usuario já me informou, e ja foi alterado, e ainda sim, não funcionou.

Comment: Então. A partir de agora, o seu problema é na interpretação do arquivo. Tenha certeza de que este arquivo esteja chamando o interpretador do PHP: `<?php` logo na primeira linha. Na sua pergunta está ok, mas vale a pena conferir. ‍♂️ - Rodei seu código simplesmente consertando os argumentos da `mail` e funcionou legal, apesar do meu ambiente não enviar de fato não enviar os emails. Ahhh! Tente, também, alterar a codificação deste arquivo. Normalmente são codificados em UTF8.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Vasques verifiquei o arquivo php.ini e está ok

Comment: Beleza, vou alterar a codificação. E obrigada pelas dicas. e está na primeira linha sim o <?php

Comment: Nada ainda, alguém tem alguma outra ideia ? Obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz um teste usando o Xampp e a página envio.php foi executada, porém, mostrou uma mensagem de erro.

Na página de envio, faça a seguinte alteração na linha 31

```
mail($destino, $assunto, $body, $headers);
```

No seu formulário, você pode alterar o botão de enviar para ficar da seguinte forma:

```
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
```

Se ao invés de executar a programação ele está imprimindo os comandos na tela, é porque o servidor não está reconhecendo a extensão .php

Como você comentou que está trabalhando com o Wordpress, creio que este tutorial vai te ajudar, ele ensina a criar um formulário de contato sem a utilização de plugins:

https://blog.da2k.com.br/2015/02/22/wordpress-criando-um-formulario-de-contato-sem-plugin-parte-1/

https://blog.da2k.com.br/2015/02/24/wordpress-criando-um-formulario-de-contato-sem-plugin-parte-2/

https://blog.da2k.com.br/2015/02/28/wordpress-criando-um-formulario-de-contato-sem-plugin-parte-3/

Comment: Olá, alterei as linhas que você disse. E não foi do mesmo jeito >:
O que posso fazer para o server reconhecer a extensão .php desse arquivo?
Estou trabalhando pelo WordPress, se é que faz diferença pra algo

Comment: Eu editei a resposta inserindo uma dica de como criar um formulário de contato personalizado com o Wordpress

Comment: Eu fiz esse tutorial, coloquei tudo inicialmente, mas continuou do mesmo jeito. 
Ai tirei algumas partes do código, como verificação se os campos estão em branco ou não, e esses detalhes que meu form já contem. E a unica diferença agora, é que recarrega a pagina, ao invés de aparecer pagina não encontrada. Mas não chega o email do mesmo jeito. Tem alguma ideia do pq o server não está executando esse arquivo da forma que deveria?

Comment: Nada ainda, tem alguma outra ideia ? Obrigada